# Count images with jquery and then output the #

Tags: jquery

I am looking to count the number of images with a certain div class name and then output the that number that is calculated to display it on a page.  Any advice on how to get this.  It would be used to let the user know how many images are in my image scroller.  Eventually I would like to figure out how to get a dynamic list like 1/10, 2/10, etc... based on what image the user is on.

here is the page so you can see what I am talking about with the scroller.

http://www.cdtto.com/site/?p=5

I have the scoller which pulls images from a custom field in worpress,  I can add as many images as I like.  I used the scrollTo.js jquery to scroll the images,  I am looking to get a count of the image and would like to have that output

Answer (score 6):

You could use this code:

```
var numImgs = $('div.myClassName img').length;
alert(numImgs);
$('div#count').text(numImgs);
```

Unlike the other examples, this one searches for the number of images contained in a div with a given class name.

Comment: Don't forget the class after img, since he was counting images with a certain class. $('div.myClassName img.myImageClass')

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery selector returns an array so just get the length of it. For example:

```
jQuery(".image").Length
```

Refer to the [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page if you need more complex selection queries. You said all the images in a div the query you'd use is something like `jQuery("div#divName img")`

Comment: `"div#divName` is unnecessary and slower. Just use `#divName`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".divClassName").find("img").length
```

is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your actual markup at http://www.cdtto.com/site/?p=5 :

```
//Count images inside element with 'feature' classname
var featureImageCount = $('div.featured img').length;

//Add element to display count to user
$('#header3 .featured-bar').after('<div>' + featureImageCount + ' Images</div>');
```

Comment: Cool, I worked it in and was able to get the image # displayed based on how many are present.  Where would I begin to try and get it to count what image we are on?  if it is the first it would display 1/3 for example.  here it is working. http://www.cdtto.com/site/?p=5